# Error 1064 la o relatie intre doua tabele in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
create table meniu (
    nume_mancare char(30),
    cantitate char(5),
    pret float,
primary key(nume_mancare));

create table bon_de_casa (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment ,
    nume_ospatar char(20),
primary key(id));

create table nota_de_plata (
    nume_mancare char(30),
    cantitate char(5),
    pret float,
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment ,
    nume_ospatar char(20),
    date DATE,
primary key(nume_mancare,id),
foreign key(nume_mancare),
foreign key(id));
```

Vreau sa stiu de ce nu merge sa creez tabelul nota_de_plata.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your code, but your "foreign key" command was wrong. This code work form me:

```
create table meniu (
    nume_mancare char(30),
    cantitate char(5),
    pret float,
primary key(nume_mancare));

create table bon_de_casa (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment ,
    nume_ospatar char(20),
primary key(id));

create table nota_de_plata (
    nume_mancare char(30),
    cantitate char(5),
    pret float,
    id int,
    nume_ospatar char(20),
    date DATE,
primary key(nume_mancare,id),
foreign key(nume_mancare) REFERENCES meniu(nume_mancare),
foreign key(id) references bon_de_casa(id));
```